# Flutter how to prevent matched PIN to not clear

Tags: flutter

I want to clear the controller only when the user initially sets a valid PIN. This is working. However, I don't want the controller to be cleared when the PIN is matched in the Re-enter screen. The previous controller was cleared when I Initially set the PIN. How can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

Here is my code

```
class _SetPinScreenState extends State<SetPinScreen> {
  TextEditingController setPinController;

  PinValidationProvider pinValidationProvider;
  bool isPinLengthValid = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setPinController = TextEditingController();
    pinValidationProvider = context.read<PinValidationProvider>();
    pinValidationProvider.resetPinValidation();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    setPinController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _validatePin(String value) {
    if (value.isNotEmpty && value.length <= 4) {
      pinValidationProvider.validatePin(value, setPinController);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isPinSet =
        context.select((PinValidationProvider provider) => provider.isPinSet);
    final isPinMatched = context
        .select((PinValidationProvider provider) => provider.isPinMatched);

    return MainTemplate(
      isFloatingButtonVisible: isPinSet,
      isFloatingActionButtonDisabled: !isPinMatched,
      floatingButtonAction: () {
        if (isPinMatched) {
          print('Select');
        }
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
                builder: (context, pinProvider, child) {
                  return Text(
                    pinProvider.isPinSet
                        ? 'Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm'
                        : 'Set PIN to Activate your Card Ending With XXXX',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 30),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                  gapSpace: 8,
                  lineHeight: 1.2,
                  colorBuilder:
                      PinListenColorBuilder(Colors.black, Colors.grey.shade400),
                ),
                onCodeChanged: _validatePin,
                codeLength: 4,
                cursor: Cursor(color: Colors.black, enabled: true),
                controller: setPinController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                currentCode: "",
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
              builder: (context, provider, child) {
                final textColor = provider.isPinSet == false
                    ? provider.isInvalidPin ||
                            (!provider.isPinMatched && provider.isPinSet)
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.black
                    : provider.isInvalidPin && !provider.isPinMatched
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.black;

                if (!provider.isPinMatched &&
                    provider.isPinSet &&
                    setPinController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                    setPinController.text.length == 4) {
                  return Center(
                    child: const Text(
                      'PIN does not match.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text(
                    'Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single digits like'
                    ' 1111 or digits in numerical order such as 1234',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: textColor,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my Provider class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PinValidationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isInvalidPin = false;

  bool get isInvalidPin => _isInvalidPin;

  bool isPinMatched = false;
  bool isPinSet = false;
  String pin = '';

  void validatePin(String pin, TextEditingController controller) {
    if (isPinSet) {
      matchPin(pin);
      return;
    }

    if (pin.length != 4) {
      _isInvalidPin = false;
    } else {
      _isInvalidPin = _isSimpleSequence(pin) || _isRepeatedDigit(pin);
      if (!_isInvalidPin) {
        isPinSet = true;
        this.pin = pin;
        controller.clear();
      }
    }
    _notifyListeners();
  }

  void matchPin(String pin) {
    isPinMatched = pin.length == 4 && pin == this.pin;
    _notifyListeners();
  }

  bool _isSimpleSequence(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      int digit1 = int.parse(pin[i]);
      int digit2 = int.parse(pin[i + 1]);

      if (digit2 - digit1 == 1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  bool _isRepeatedDigit(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pin[i] == pin[i + 1]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  void _notifyListeners() {
    Future.microtask(() {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void resetPinValidation() {
    _isInvalidPin = false;
    isPinSet = false;
    pin = '';
    isPinMatched = false;
    _notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PinFieldAutoFill  from the sms_autofill widget looks for the current code, which is in this case always an empty string. Your build call will reset this widget, because it checks for this attribute instead of the value in the TextEditingController.

Try to set the currentCode to this:

```
currentCode: setPinController.text
```

Comment: I tried but still controller clear when my PIN matched

Comment: my floating button will be disabled first when he enter match PIN then it enable the floating button but controller cleared immediately when PIN matched

Comment: Do you call resetPinValidation anywhere else in your code? I only see 2 places where isPinSet is set to true (in validatePin) and to false (in resetPinValidation). Does your initState called again after you press the FloatiingActionButton so it calls resetPinValidation twice?

Comment: yes, i created `resetPinValidation` as i want to dispose provider

Comment: Where do you call this? If you call this function after you entered a correct pin, isPinSet will be false again. This will be true in the if in my posted answer, so the controller gets cleared again.

Comment: i only called `resetPinValidation` in `initState`

Comment: so how to dispose the provider so that value don't saved when i go back .

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all ... This is only 1 page right? So your initState is called only once, right? So if you enter your first pin, initState isn't called again, right? If you navigate back and open this page again, initState is called, right? If yes, this should work. You should restart your programm, stop the current run and try again ..

Comment: yes i have only one page, and this is whole code which i am showing to you.

and i try to restart app still after Match PIN my controller clear.

Comment: Hmmm .... my last guess is: the notifyListener call in your matchPin resets your Pin Widget. I found the sms_autofill package and in the documentation i found the currentCode attribute, which is an empty string in your case. If you call notifyListeners your widget calls the built method again and your pin widget looks for currentCode instead of the value inside your TextEditingController. Try to set the currentCode to this: currentCode: setPinController.text

Comment: No problem, I have updated the answer in case people have the same problem in the future :D